# Restricting the user to not get a new view on changing the URL id value

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC and we are using MVC 3.0 for our project..

We do have a flow like serach_view => results_view => details_view..

we do have a jQgrid in the results view..if the user click on any one of the rows they will get redirected to a details view.. (this has to be done with jqgrid onselected row)

now the URL will be like this mysite/controller/detials/ 1

now I have to make sure that the user should go back to the results view to get the next record in the grid.

but in MVC we can get the next record by mysite/controller/details/2 (changing the id value)

how can I control this...My requirement is user needs to go back to the results page to get the next records..not directly from the details page..we need to stop some data scraping..
Please help me..
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't *control* this. That's what pretty URLs such as `controller/detials/1` are used for => so that the user can easily navigate the site by simply modifying the URL.

This being said you have the possibility of serving the details view through a controller action decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute forcing POST verb. This way if the user types  `controller/detials/2` in the address bar of his browser he will get a 404 error. And inside the jqGrid you will use a HTML `<form>` with POST method instead of a link in order to navigate to this details view.

Comment: i don't know either your solution is best or not..but its working fine that way..i created a form and onselectedrow event of jqgrid i am doing the submit of that form...thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

According to

> Darin Dimitrov

I did like this

```
<form id="form-details" name="formdetails" action=""></form>
```

in jqgrid

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {

                        var url = '@Url.Content("~/Search/Details/")' + id;
                        $("#form-details").attr("action", url);
                        document.forms.detailsform.submit()

                    },
```

that did the trick..and in my controller actionresult i only have the action result like

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
}
```

no direct

```
 public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
    }
```

that way it will only accept posts..

Please correct me if i did anything wrong according to best practices..but the above code is working fine...thanks a lot Darin Dimitrov and StackOverflow..

Regards,
Sunny